# DocumentDB Change Feed - How to see all changes to a document

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

This new [Change Feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-change-feed) feature provided by DocumentDB is pretty cool. However, the documentation states:

> Each change to a document appears only once in the change feed. Only the most recent change for a given document is included in the change log. Intermediate changes may not be available.

Basically, if a document goes from revision A->B->C, when the change feed is polled, we're only going to get "C." - I have a situation where I want to see "A" and "B" as well.

I know of a few existing patterns to solve this, but I was really hoping to leverage this new Change Feed feature. I hoped it would return A, B, and C.

Is the intent of this feature to have "workers" polling the service very frequently? Obviously, the more frequently workers poll, the less likely they are to skip a revision to a document. However, I wouldn't want to adversely affect performance of the collection as a result.

Comment: Just thinking out loud, can't you use DocumentDB triggers for this purpose - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-programming#a-idtriggera-database-triggers? You could have a trigger fire after every document update that will have code to identify the change and log the changes somewhere.

Comment: Correct, a trigger could allow me to capture the diff. I would then either embed the changes in the document itself or in a separate document. Either are fairly common patterns depending on the number of updates expected. However, I have an external system that needs to see ALL versions, for data warehousing purposes. That's the problem with just a trigger+sproc.

Comment: But for anyone else's benefit reading this... It would definitely be possible to 1) use the trigger to capture the diffs, 2) embed the diffs in the document, 3) detect the updated document in Change Feed, 4) handle the situation in which you've already "processed" updates 0-[i-1] and 5) handle the situation in which you're seeing more than one "new" update in the same iteration. - It's just more maintenance + coding. I was hoping to just have a stream of ALL updates to a document since the last call to the Change Feed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

DocumentDB team member here. I'll start off saying please propose/vote for support for all versions/generations of the document here: http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb

The intent of Change Feed supporting the latest version was for two reasons:

1. Many problems like data synchronization, and stream processing rely on the latest version, and do not need the intermediate versions
2. This approach has the advantage of not requiring additional storage to store all versions or having a time period for change feed availability.

You had mentioned you're already aware of workarounds, but I'll just state this for the benefit of others: this problem can be solved by inverting what's stored in DocumentDB. That is, you can store all versions in DocumentDB via creating new documents, then consolidate them via change feed by upserting the latest version.

To answer the question in comments, you **must absolutely use Change Feed over querying by timestamp** for the following reasons:

1. Change Feed is much more efficient. Querying "order by timestamp" across a distributed dataset performs a global sort, whereas Change Feed sorts locally within partitions timestamp partially. Additionally, there's no query parsing overhead
2. Clock time is less meaningful in distributed systems due to clock skew, and differentiating between multiple updates within a second/millisecond can be important. Instead, you need the "logical time" representing the exact commit order within the database. With change feed, updates within a partition key are in exact order of commit, and you get all documents updated within a transaction stamped with the same logical timestamp.
3. Change Feed can be consumed in a distributed manner across multiple workers unlike query. This is great when working with a downstream scalable compute framework like Apache Storm or Azure Functions.

Comment: Hi Aravind. Thank you for the response. I figured the reason was due to additional storage costs.

Comment: Aravind - any chance you could shed some light on the benefit of this feature versus a client that is continuously running a query that selects against an auto-update-timestamp? Are there performance differences perhaps? It seems like cost is a factor. The query would incur RU cost for running the query, whereas Change Feed claims that no other costs are incurred aside from pulling the documents over the wire?

Comment: Many reasons. 1) Much more efficient. Querying "order by timestamp" across a distributed dataset is less efficient compared to ordered by timestamp partially within partitions/key ranges. Additionally, there's no query parsing overhead ...

Comment: 2) Time is less meaningful in distributed systems due to clock skew, and differentiating between multiple updates within a second/millisecond can be important, i.e. you want the "logical timestamp" representing the exact commit order within the database. For example, you get all documents updated within a transaction stamped with the same logical timestamp, and always receive the latest update for a document, and updates within a partition key are in exact order of commit. and ...

Comment: 3) change feed can be consumed in a distributed manner across multiple workers unlike query. This is great when working with a downstream scalable compute framework like Apache Storm or Azure Functions

Comment: It would be *much* better to have the original answer edited with additional information, vs posting additional info in comments.

Comment: @AravindKrishnaR. What about transactions? Assuming a source collection containing all versions, how would a transaction that generates new versions of several documents be propagated atomically to the "consolidated" second collection ?

Comment: @CristiDiaconescu all documents updated in the same transaction will be stamped with the same _lsn value and returned in the same page of results, and you can apply them transactionally to the destination

Comment: It the same document with original statement ("Each change to a document appears only once in the change feed. Only the most recent change for a given document is included in the change log. Intermediate changes may not be available."). it has controversial statement "You can read the change feed for historic items, for example, items that were added five years ago. If the item is not deleted you can read the change feed as far as the origin of your container." https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed#change-feed-and-different-operations. It is confusing Could you clarify?

Comment: Will reword the doc to make it clearer. But it's technically true - since change feed has the latest version of every document, if a doc was created 5 years ago and never updated, it would still show up in the change feed. This property is useful if you're trying to synchronize data in Cosmos DB with another destination.