# Get history of Document modifications/revisions in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: json, azure-cosmosdb

I am looking for a sample code to get history of Document modifications , in the form of a list of  Document versions in Azure Cosmos DB.

By selecting a document version from the list , that version will be displayed.
I also want to restore a previous document version .

I get the last version using the _ts tag.

However want a complete history of document revisions. 
1. Maybe using Cosmos DB change feed. 
2. Reading the ReadDocumentFeed 
I have done some research . However did not come across any code for this.
Any pointers in this direction are most welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DocumentDB Change Feed - How to see all changes to a document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176105/documentdb-change-feed-how-to-see-all-changes-to-a-document)

Comment: @NickChapsas Oh yes...i seem to have missed this one. Thanks. Will have a look at it.